# How to pull data from mysql database and visualize with D3.JS?

Tags: mysql, json, d3.js, visualization

I have a database in `MySQL` which I want to visualize in `D3.JS`. In order to do that, first I want to `parse` the data in `JSON` format, then write a basic code which pulls data from database and visualize with `D3.JS`. I look around but couldn't find what I want since I'm new to `D3.JS`.

How can I achieve that? Any help or clue appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

The following is a php script that you should be able to save somewhere as a file (let's say you call it 'getdata.php') accessible from your HTML file with your D3 code in it. When called it will return data from your MySQL database in a json format (so long as the database server isn't outside your domain);

```
<?php
    $username = "******"; 
    $password = "******";   
    $host = "******";
    $database="***dbase_name***";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "
    query here
    ";

    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    mysql_close($server);
?>
```

Obviously you would need to enter appropriate details for username, password, host and database. You would also need to include an appropriate query for your data so that it returned what you were looking for. Something along the lines of (and this is only a guess);

```
SELECT `dateTimeTaken`, `reading` FROM `tablename`
```

Which would return a list of time stamps and values from a table called `tablename` with columns called `dateTimeTaken` and `reading`.
Then when you go to read in your json file you would use the following syntax for the code where you would be reading in your json;

```
d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, data) {
```

Hopefully that's close to what you're looking for. I've tested it locally and it all seems to work..

I've put together a post to go over local installation of a simple WAMP server and setting up a query on the MySQL database from d3.js here http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html

This is pretty much the same situation as [Accessing MySQL database in d3 visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679610/accessing-mysql-database-in-d3-visualization/14683311#14683311)

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Web Service.

Basically, you'd want to make a web service that will return json data (for instance) to connect to `d3.json()` calls.

I would recommend you to use Python to quickly do something extending `SimpleHTTPServer`, or go with a web service framework such as [web2py](http://web2py.com).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there aren't any libraries that allow javascript to connect to a MySQL database directly. Instead consider exposing your data via a web service (using any number of server side technologies: ASP.Net, PHP, Ruby on Rails etc) and serialise your data to JSON in the response

Comment: What do you suggest me to start with?

Comment: If none of that makes sense, you may want to export your data manually from MySQL as .csv (something like phpmysqladmin has this option, or you can do on command line) and then directly load that .csv into D3, which has a csv loading tool. (Or if you export using tabs as the delimiter, use the D3 "tsv" import.) It's not dynamic, but you'll get up and running much faster than stepping back to learn a whole new framework.

Comment: @ChrisWilson I don't have direct access to database and I will use this at real time visualization.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced problem myself with json_encode, in the end I wrote my own code instead of json_encode. Just you need to set the sql and yoru connection info. Hope you find it useful.

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_Host, DB_User, DB_Password, DB_Name) or die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
$sql = "select  AID as id, deDate_Value as date, nterTime AS counter 
        from xxxx";

//Get the Date and store it in array
$records = array();
if ( $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) )
    while ( $obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result) )
        $records[] = $obj;

//echo in json format on screen       
echo "[";
$comma_1 = "";
foreach($records as $obj)
{
    echo $comma_1."{";
    $comma_2 = "";
    foreach($obj as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $comma_2.'"'.$key."\": \"". $value . "\"";
        $comma_2 = ", ";
    }
    echo "}";
    $comma_1 = ", \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get d3.json to work, I had to call it the following way (my PHP file generates the JSON data):

```
d3.json("InventoryData.php").then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery which is more popular as follows:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
console.log(data);
}
```