# D3 get JSON data from mysql always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I have done a lot R&D, tried lots of question on stackoverflow and from other site too but unable to understand what i am doing wrong. I will be really thankful if help me to point where i am wrong.

Also tried this too if code is skipping before response but not use.
[Returning array from d3.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656580/returning-array-from-d3-json)

**D3 code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    d3.json("chart_data.php", function(error, data){
        json_Data = data;
        console.log("Error:"+error);
        console.log(json_Data);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Console for error is**

```
Error:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

**Console for data is**

```
undefined
```

**If I run php file direct in browser I am getting:**

```
[{"value":"1","date":"2016-03-29"},{"value":"0","date":"2016-03-30"},{"value":"3","date":"2016-03-31"},{"value":"2","date":"2016-04-01"},{"value":"2","date":"2016-04-02"},{"value":"5","date":"2016-04-03"},{"value":"1","date":"2016-04-04"},{"value":"1","date":"2016-04-05"},{"value":"0","date":"2016-04-06"}]
```

**This is my PHP**

```
<?php
require 'db_connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT `y-axis` as value, `x-axis` as date FROM site_data";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $count = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$count]['value'] = $row['value'];
        $data[$count]['date']  = $row['date'];
        $count++;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
$con->close();
?>
```

**DB connection file**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","analytic");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

PHP file and D3 file is on same directory.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have posted.  I'm guessing there is something else that isn't posted.

Comment: That's all except this there would be just db_connection file. This is why i am also confused that everywhere code is same why not running for me

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a php file through as a parameter to d3.json() ?

Comment: @Keven i want to get data from DB, for that i need to use PHP with MySql.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384774/how-to-pull-data-from-mysql-database-and-visualize-with-d3-js you can get JSON like this

Comment: @FarhanBaloch See my updated comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a .php file as a parameter to d3.json() try passing a .json file:

```
d3.json("chart_data.json", function(error, data){
    json_Data = data;
    console.log("Error:"+error);
    console.log(json_Data);
});
```

Use php to get the code from the DB and convert it to json using something like `json_encode`.  Output that data in a .json file.  Don't try to read json directly from a .php file.

Comment: Are you asking me to write JSON file via PHP and then I can read JSON file. I have option to write tsv file too but i was wondering why it is not working like that. anyways thanks for your help I will vote up once I will make this

Comment: For now, just try creating a separate .json file manually to test.  Only put the json in it and call it.  If it works then you know what the problem is.  If not, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Everything was ok issue was with my machine :). Anyways this solution is also good